# xcode - Remove spring effect from dropdown selection box

Tags: ios, xcode

I have inherited some code that shows a dropdown selection box which, until now, only had a few options in it. I now need to add more options, but if they exceed the screensize, it is possible to scroll to them, but it 'springs' back again. My desired effect is that you can just scroll through the list moving it up or down (without it spring back down again).

The current behavior is that you click on the option box, the options appear, but exceed the screen size, therefore you can scroll them, but it springs back again so you are never able to select them.

The desired behavior is that you scroll the list, but it doesn't spring back down again, thus allowing you to select an option that is above the top of the screen.

This appears to be the code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *aCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"options" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    UILabel *lblValue = [aCell viewWithTag:100];
    [lblValue setText:[[AppDelegate sharedAppDelegate] arrLIST][indexPath.row][@"options"]];

    if ([lblValue.text isEqualToString:lblChannel.text])
        [aCell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:(240.0/255.0) green:(240.0/255.0) blue:(240.0/255.0) alpha:1.0]];
    else
        [aCell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];  
    return aCell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like an issue with Autolayout constraints set wit the table view and its container view. If you cannot fix the conmtratints for some reason try experimenting with setting Content Insets for the bottom of the table view.

Comment: Thank you for replying, but I did not understand what you said I'm afraid. I'll continue to investigate to see if I can find out why it is happening. Thank you.